# Is it possible to run the GNOME user manager from XFCE4?

Tags: gnome, configuration, xfce, users

If I run 'gnome-control-center' and click on the 'User Accounts' icon, the gnome-control-center crashes.

I built it from source to see what's going on, and it turns out it's doing a

```
if (strcmp(getenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"), "GNOME"))
```

in panels/user-accounts/um-password-dialog.c, line 690.

I don't have an environment variable "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP", so the getenv is returning NULL, and the strcmp is segfaulting

Where is XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP meant to be defined?  And shouldn't gnome-control-center check the pointer returned by getenv before passing it to strcmp?

Does xfce4 have its own 'User Accounts' tool for creating new users?

**Edit**:

I was asked in a comment to run this:

```
chris@chris:~$ env | grep XDG
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=eeeeeeeeaaaaaaaa2222222200000000-1111111122.555544-444444448
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xfce:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share
chris@chris:~$
```

Comment: I think there should be xdg. What do you get when you do `env | grep XDG` ? There are some commandline tool like `useradd` and `adduser`.

Comment: I updated my question with the output from that command.  I changed the session cookie.  I also found that adding "export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=" to my .xprofile allows me to use the GNOME user manager.

Answer (score 1):

Under XFCE, execute the command users-admin and you should get this:
[image]